# what is a read() in c language

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>       
#include <fcntl.h>         
#include <unistd.h>        

#define  BUFF_SIZE   5     

int main()
{
   char     buff[BUFF_SIZE];
   int      fd;
   ssize_t  rd_size;

   if ( 0 < ( fd = open( "./test.txt", O_RDONLY)))
   {
      while( 0 < ( rd_size = read( fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE-1)))   
   {
       buff[rd_size]  = '\0';      
       puts( buff);
   }
   close( fd);
   }
   else
   {
      printf( "File Fail..\n");
   }
   return 0;
   }

   as a result..


     1234
     5
     AB
     CDE

     abcd
     e
     67
     890
```

here is test.txt .

```
12345
ABCDE
abcde
67890
```

i cannot understand why the result of this program.
i'm sorry; i don't know english very much.

i know the value, 1234
but, the next values I don't.

Please help me understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists no function called `read()` in the C language.

This function is a common non-standard extension used by some specific operative systems, such as Unix and MS DOS. They implemented it in compiler- and system-specific ways.

Later on, the function became standardized with [POSIX version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) of the function. It would seem that your code uses that version.

Comment: Unix and MS DOS?  Did I stumble onto a comment from 1995?  :)

Comment: @BrandonYates No, you stumbled into ancient, non-standard functions, that really don't make much sense to use today.

Comment: I suppose it would depend on what level of abstraction you're working at. Someone working on the C library or in kernel space would need to use these essential standard system calls.

Answer (score 5):

The program does precisely what you instructed it to do: read four bytes at a time from the file, and print out those four-byte blocks on a line each.

Comment: Four bytes, actually.

Comment: @interjay: That's what I said!